# Random variables $X_n,\,n\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\mathrm{P}(|X_n|>\frac1n)\to 0$, but $X_n\nrightarrow 0$ a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

> Find an example of a sequence of rv's $(X_n)$ defined on a probability space $(\varOmega, \mathcal{F},\mathrm{P})$ such that $\mathrm{P}(|X_n|>\frac1n)\to 0$, but $X_n\nrightarrow 0$ a.s. on $\varOmega$.

*Attept.* Of course I worked on $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda),$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$, but examples like $X_n(x)=n \mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x)$ do not work.

Thanks an advance for the help.

Comment: Take independent random variables $(X_n)$ such that $\mathbb P(X_n = 0) = 1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $\mathbb P(X_n = 1) = \frac{1}{n}$. Obviously $\mathbb P(|X_n| > \frac{1}{n})$ tends to $0$, while by borel cantelli, they won't tend to $0$ almost surely (the series $\sum \mathbb P(X_n =1)$ diverges)

Comment: Thank you, very enlightening, indeed. You may post in as an answer if you prefer, in order to accept it.

Comment: There is still an error 11 hours after you posted the question even tough   the mistake has been pointed out. Make sure that the title matches the question. It is also not clear whether you want an explicit construction of the probability space random variables or just their existence.

Comment: Question just edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be probability space on which we can define sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$, such that:

$\mu_n = (1-\frac{1}{n})\delta_0 + \frac{1}{n}\delta_1$, where $\mu_n $ is distribution of $X_n \ \big($that is $\mathbb P(X_n=1) = \frac{1}{n} = 1 - \mathbb P(X_n = 0 ) \big)$

And the family $\{ X_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is independent.

Then we have (for $n\ge 2$) $\mathbb P(|X_n| > \frac{1}{n}) = \mathbb P(X_n = 1) = \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

We can say even more, taking any $\epsilon > 0$, then $\mathbb P(|X_n| > \epsilon) \to 0$, which means that $X_n \to 0$ in probability.

To show that sequence $(X_n)$ doesn't converge to $0$ $\mathbb P-$almost surely, we will use Borel-Cantelli lemma. Note that due to independence of the family $\{X_n\}$ we have that events $\{ X_n = 1 \}$ are independent, too. Moreover $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X_n = 1) = \infty$, so by B-C lemma we have $\mathbb P(\limsup \{X_n = 1\}) = 1$

This means that we have set of measure $1$, where we cannot have convergence to $0$, since for any $\omega \in \limsup \{X_n = 1\}$, we have countable sequence $n_k(\omega)$ such that $X_{n_k(\omega)}(\omega) = 1$. By that, the condition $\forall_{\epsilon > 0} \exists_{N \in \mathbb N} \forall_{n > N} |X_n(\omega)| < \epsilon$ is violated. So we even showed that not only $(X_n)$ does not converge to $0$ almost surely, but it almost surely diverges! (Since only possible limit due to convergence in probability is $0$)

Answer (score 1):

The first example provides  Dominik Kutek in comment. It would be right to ask him to fill out this comment as an answer and accept it.

I provide another well-known example. You can slightly modify your sequence on the probability space $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)$. The key property is that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n=\infty$. We turn the segment $[0,1]$ into a circle, gluing its beginning and end. We will postpone segments $A_n$ with a length of $1/n$ sequentially so that the next segment begins where the previous one ends. Since the harmonic series diverges, the segments will “spin” around the circle an unlimited number of times. Then we can take $X_n=n\cdot \mathbb 1_{A_n}$. 
Here $A_n$ is 
$$
A_{\color{red}{1}}=[0,\color{red}{1}], \; A_{\color{red}{2}}=[0,\color{red}{\tfrac12}], \; A_{\color{red}{3}}=[\tfrac12,\tfrac12+\color{red}{\tfrac13}]=[\tfrac12,\tfrac56], \; A_4=[\tfrac56, 1]\cup[0,\tfrac1{12}],
$$
(note that $\tfrac56+\tfrac14=1+\tfrac{1}{12}>1$, so we continue the set $A_4$ from zero)
$$
A_{\color{red}5}=[\tfrac{1}{12},\tfrac{1}{12}+\color{red}{\tfrac15}]=[\tfrac{1}{12},\tfrac{17}{60}],\; A_{\color{red}6}=[\tfrac{17}{60},\tfrac{17}{60}+\color{red}{\tfrac16}]=[\tfrac{17}{60},\tfrac{27}{60}]
$$
and so on. Note that each point of the segment an unlimited number of times falls into the sets $A_n$. So, for any $\omega\in[0,1]$, there exist a sequence $n_k$ such that $X_{n_k}(\omega)=n_k\to\infty$. Therefore $X_n$ does not converge a.s. to zero.